# Overriding authentication behavior in jclouds

Tags: java, jclouds

I'm looking to leverage RackSpace's CloudFiles platform for large object storage (word docs, images, etc).  Following some of their guides, I found a useful code snippet, that looks like it should work, but doesn't in my case.

```
    Iterable<Module> modules = ImmutableSet.<Module> of(
            new Log4JLoggingModule());
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(LocationConstants.PROPERTY_ZONE, ZONE);
    properties.setProperty(LocationConstants.PROPERTY_REGION, "ORD");
    CloudFilesClient cloudFilesClient = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(PROVIDER)
            .credentials(username, apiKey)
            .overrides(properties)
            .modules(modules)
            .buildApi(CloudFilesClient.class);
```

The problem is that when this code executes, it tries to log me in the IAD (Virginia) instance of CloudFiles.  My organization's goal is to use the ORD (Chicago) instance as primary to be colocated with our cloud and use DFW as a back up environment.  The login response results in the IAD instance coming back first, so I'm assuming JClouds is using that.  Browsing around, it looks like the ZONE/REGION attributes are ignored for CloudFiles.  I was wondering if there is any way to override the code that comes back for authentication to loop through the returned providers and choose which one to login to.

Update:

The accepted answer is mostly good, with some more info available in this snippet:

```
    RestContext<CommonSwiftClient, CommonSwiftAsyncClient> swift = cloudFilesClient.unwrap();
    CommonSwiftClient client = swift.getApi();
    SwiftObject object = client.newSwiftObject();

    object.getInfo().setName(FILENAME + SUFFIX);
    object.setPayload("This is my payload."); //input stream.
    String id = client.putObject(CONTAINER, object);
    System.out.println(id);
    SwiftObject obj2 = client.getObject(CONTAINER,FILENAME + SUFFIX);
    System.out.println(obj2.getPayload());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are working on the next version of jclouds (1.7.1) that should include multi-region support for Rackspace Cloud Files and [OpenStack Swift](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-labs-openstack/tree/master/openstack-swift). In the meantime you might be able to use this code as a workaround.

```
private void uploadToRackspaceRegion() {
  Iterable<Module> modules = ImmutableSet.<Module> of(new Log4JLoggingModule());
  String provider = "swift-keystone"; //Region selection is limited to swift-keystone provider
  String identity = "username";
  String credential = "password";
  String endpoint = "https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/";
  String region = "ORD";

  Properties overrides = new Properties();
  overrides.setProperty(LocationConstants.PROPERTY_REGION, region);
  overrides.setProperty(Constants.PROPERTY_API_VERSION, "2");

  BlobStoreContext context = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(provider)
        .endpoint(endpoint)
        .credentials(identity, credential)
        .modules(modules)
        .overrides(overrides)
        .buildView(BlobStoreContext.class);
  RestContext<CommonSwiftClient, CommonSwiftAsyncClient> swift = context.unwrap();
  CommonSwiftClient client = swift.getApi();

  SwiftObject uploadObject = client.newSwiftObject();
  uploadObject.getInfo().setName("test.txt");
  uploadObject.setPayload("This is my payload."); //input stream.

  String eTag = client.putObject("jclouds", uploadObject);
  System.out.println("eTag = " + eTag);

  SwiftObject downloadObject = client.getObject("jclouds", "test.txt");
  System.out.println("downloadObject = " + downloadObject.getPayload());

  context.close();
}
```

Use `swift` as you would Cloud Files. Keep in mind that if you need to use Cloud Files CDN stuff, the above won't work for that. Also, know that this way of doing things will eventually be deprecated.

Comment: I tried this originally, One problem with this type of example is that the swift and storage variables aren't defined.  Can you also comment how you would use swift to get a specific container?  This was missing from the website comment as well.

Comment: Ok, so I played a bit further.  I'm only able to get it to work if I use password credentials, not with an API key.  API key results in a 400.

Comment: I'm marking the answer as accepted.  The API key issue is still a problem, but I can at least login using username/password.  For those curious, another way to look at storage and swift is in my original.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you feedback John. I updated my example to be complete.